# How to access value in array of structs?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, google-bigquery

I'm using Spark on Google Cloud to process data from Google Analytics but I don't know how to select custom dimensions based on index

The structure of GA's custom dimension is the fallowing:

```
ARRAY<STRUCT< index: INTEGER, value:STRING >>
```

Usually, in BigQuery, I would do a subquery to select the data like

```
SELECT (select value from customDimensions where index = 2)
```

But as explained in [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Subqueries+in+SELECT) subquery in select is not yet supported.

Comment: Have you tried using UNSET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Know nothing about Spark on Google Cloud, but if it's close enough to Apache Spark you can use [element_at](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) function that returns the element of the array at the given index in value if column is array followed by `dot` accessor.

```
// create a sample dataset
val structData = Seq((0,"zero"), (1, "one")).toDF("id", "value")
val data = structData
  .select(struct("id", "value") as "s")
  .groupBy()
  .agg(collect_list("s") as "a")

// the schema matches the requirements
scala> data.printSchema
root
 |-- a: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)

data.createOrReplaceTempView("customDimensions")
```

The following query won't work since `index` is not known.

```
scala> sql("select value from customDimensions where index = 2").show
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`index`' given input columns: [customdimensions.a]; line 1 pos 41;
'Project ['value]
+- 'Filter ('index = 2)
   +- SubqueryAlias `customdimensions`
      +- Aggregate [collect_list(s#9, 0, 0) AS a#13]
         +- Project [named_struct(id, id#5, value, value#6) AS s#9]
            +- Project [_1#2 AS id#5, _2#3 AS value#6]
               +- LocalRelation [_1#2, _2#3]
...
```

Let's use `element_at` standard function instead.

```
scala> sql("select element_at(a, 2) from customDimensions").show
+----------------+
|element_at(a, 2)|
+----------------+
|        [1, one]|
+----------------+
```

The "array" is a struct and so you can use `.` (dot).

```
scala> sql("select element_at(a, 2).value from customDimensions").show
+----------------------+
|element_at(a, 2).value|
+----------------------+
|                   one|
+----------------------+
```